# why doesn't update_all work in rails with mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a User and Notification model, User has_many Notification. The notifications are paged by kaminari:
Notification model definition,

```
class Notification
  ...
  field read, type: Boolean, default: false
  belongs_to :user
  scope :recent, ->(source) { where(source: source).desc(:created_at) }
  ...
end
```

In the notification controller,

```
@notifications = current_user.notifications.recent(@source).page(params[:page])
```

then I want to change the read attribute to true after rending the current page but it doesnt work:

```
@notifications.update_all(read: true)
```

The *read* attribute hasn't been changed there. And I also have 1 tricky things:

1. when removing the scope directive(recent), update_all can work but it updates not only the current user but also all the others.

I find some logs in my thin server, but I don't find errors:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=cse_development collection=notifi
cations selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"509765c42061c79036000004", "source"=>"t
opic"}, "$orderby"=>{"created_at"=>-1}} update={"$set"=>{:read=>true}} flags=[:m
ulti] (0.9999ms)
```

Do I miss something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@notifications.update_all(:read => true)
```

Comment: I tried your ides, but it doesn't work for me. One addition, my ruby version is 1.9.3, so I think hash can be written by read:true. I guessed the method 'update_all' can only work on a criteria object, but the paged one '@notifications' is an array object. Unfortunately, it didn't hit the root cause...